# Romanian amateur radio license

Tags: license, europe

## Romanian amateur radio license

Hello. I am wondering how to get a amateur license in Romania, and whether there is any material on this. I am licensed in the US, am a Romanian citizen, and can speak Romanian, so that should not be a problem. I did a bit of research myself, but did not really find anything.

Comment: Does the website of the Romanian national club [FRR](http://www.hamradio.ro/) provide anything at all (I can't read Romanian)?

Answer (score 4):

In Romania, this is governed by ANCOM (Autoritatea Natională pentru Administrare si Reglementare în Comunicatii).

Since you already have a US Amateur radio license, there are two possible scenarios:

1. Articles 26, 27 and 28 apply if the radio amateur already holds an equivalent CEPT authorization or the administration of the country of origin has signed a reciprocity agreement with Romania.
2. In order to obtain a Romanian radio call sign ( YO X ABC), you must have a CEPT equivalent amateur radio certificate or an amateur radio license valid in your country of origin. In this case, Articles 17 and 18 of the Radio Regulations apply. In this case, the basic is the document "certifying the stay or residence on the territory of Romania".

However, for those who are unlicensed, the ANCOM document entitled "DECISION
on the regulation of amateur service", look at chapter 2 for that information.  Here is an excerpt:

> CHAPTER II - Certification of radio amateurs
>
> Art. 9. - (1) The amateur radio certificate is obtained on the basis
> of an exam which consists of tests specific to each class. (2) The
> examination programs for obtaining the amateur radio certificate are
> available on the ANCOM website, by reference to the documents of the
> Conference of European Postal and Telecommunications Administrations,
> hereinafter referred to as CEPT.
>
> Art. 10. - (1) The amateur radio certificates are of 4 classes: class
> I, class II, class III and class IV. (2) Class I and Class II
> certificates are equivalent to the Harmonized Certificate of
> Examination for Amateur Service (HAREC) established under CEPT. (3)
> The third class certificate is equivalent to the CEPT Novice
> certificate. (4) The 4th grade certificate is equivalent to the CEPT
> Entry-Class certificate .
>
> Art. 11. - (1) The exams are organized every six months. (2) In
> addition to the half-yearly sessions, after analyzing the received
> requests, ANCOM may also organize additional examination sessions,
> including at home, in the case of persons with disabilities.
>
> Art. 12. - (1) In order to register for the examination, the applicant
> submits a standard form. (2) The standard form shall be submitted at
> least 5 working days before the date of the exam. (3) The following
> shall be attached to the standard form, available on the ANCOM
> website: a)
> copy of the identity card or of the document attesting the stay or residence on the Romanian
> territory, issued by the Romanian state; b) in the case of a minor, a
> copy of the identity card or birth certificate, as the case may be,
> accompanied by a copy of the identity card or document certifying the
> stay or residence in Romania, issued by the Romanian state to the
> parent, guardian or legal guardian, such as and his statement, on his
> own responsibility, regarding the agreement to carry out and assume
> responsibility for the amateur radio activity of the minor applicant.
> (4) At the examination, the applicant presents, in original, the
> identity document provided in par. (3) lit. a) or letter b), as the
> case may be. (5) In order to take the examination in order to obtain
> the Class II amateur radio certificate, the applicant must hold a
> Class III amateur radio license obtained at least 12 months before the
> date of the examination. (6) In order to take the examination in order
> to obtain the Class I amateur radio certificate, the applicant must
> hold a Class II amateur radio license obtained at least 12 months
> before the date of the examination. (7) The applicant who has not
> reached the age of 14 years until the date of participation in the
> exam, can only register for obtaining the certificate of amateur radio
> class IV.
>
> Art. 13. - (1) In order to be declared “admitted” to the exam, the
> candidate must pass all the tests for the respective class. (2) The
> candidate who did not pass all the tests may request the registration
> in order to repeat the non-promoted test / tests within maximum 1 year
> from their initial support, in any subsequent session organized by
> ANCOM. (3) The candidate who fails to pass the remaining outstanding
> evidence within the term provided in par. (2) is declared "rejected".
>
> Art. 14. - (1) In order to obtain the first and second class amateur
> radio certificates, the examination tests and the evaluation scales
> are the following: a) electronics and radio: the test includes a set
> of 20 questions; a minimum of 15 correct answers are required for
> promotion; b) labor protection: the test includes a set of 10
> questions; a minimum of 7 correct answers are required for promotion;
> c) operating rules and procedures: the test includes a set of 8
> questions; a minimum of 6 correct answers are required for promotion;
> d) domestic and international regulations: the test includes a set of
> 25 questions; a minimum of 20 correct answers are required for
> promotion. (2) In order to obtain the Class III amateur radio
> certificate, the examination tests and assessment scales are as
> follows: a) electronics and radio: the test includes a set of 16
> questions; a minimum of 12 correct answers are required for promotion;
> b) labor protection: the test includes a set of 10 questions; a
> minimum of 7 correct answers are required for promotion; c) operating
> rules and procedures: the test includes a set of 8 questions; a
> minimum of 6 correct answers are required for promotion; d) domestic
> and international regulations: the test includes a set of 20
> questions; a minimum of 15 correct answers are required for promotion.
> (3) In order to obtain the Class IV amateur radio certificate, the
> examination tests and assessment scales are as follows: a) labor
> protection: the test includes a set of 10 questions; a minimum of 7
> correct answers are required for promotion; b) operating rules and
> procedures: the test includes a set of 8 questions; a minimum of 6
> correct answers are required for promotion; c) domestic and
> international regulations: the test includes a set of 20 questions; a
> minimum of 15 correct answers are required for promotion. (4)
> Irrespective of the examination test, all questions have four answer
> options, of which only one is correct and complete.
>
> Article 15. - (1) The results of the tests are published on the ANCOM
> website within a maximum of 15 working days from the date of the exam.
> (2) Any appeals regarding the results of the tests shall be submitted
> within 3 working days from the date of publication of the results. The
> answer to the appeal is communicated in writing to the person who
> submitted it, within 30 working days from the date of registration of
> the appeal.
>
> Art. 16. - ANCOM issues the amateur radio certificates to the
> candidates declared “admitted” within 15 days from the date of
> submission of a recent color photograph, 3x4 cm passport type or a
> color photograph transmitted in electronic format with a resolution of
> at least 300 dpi and ratio 9: 7.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting an excerpt from @Joshua's answer:

> a) electronics and radio: the test includes a set of 16 questions; a minimum of 12 correct answers are required for promotion; b) labor protection: the test includes a set of 10 questions; a minimum of 7 correct answers are required for promotion; c) operating rules and procedures: the test includes a set of 8 questions; a minimum of 6 correct answers are required for promotion; d) domestic and international regulations: the test includes a set of 20 questions; a minimum of 15 correct answers are required for promotion.

When you participate in an exam session (ordinary or extraordinary) organized by ANCOM, there are the above four separate subjects. One of the best resources available online to prepare for the exam is [this web site](http://examyo.scienceontheweb.net/). It is a database of questions that have been asked in previous exam sessions.

A list of the currently scheduled exam sessions can be found [here](https://www.ancom.ro/sesiuni-examinare_3538).

Not sure how helpful Google Translate is with the two links that I shared, especially the first one, so that you understand what you're learning.